# Problem with prisma .upsert, Unkown argument

Tags: javascript, postgresql, prisma

I have problem with prisma upsert(), I get info:

> PrismaClientValidationError:  Invalid `prisma.prismaUser.upsert()`
> invocation:
>
> {   where: {
> email: 'viola@prisma.io'
> ~~~~~   },   update: {
> name: 'Viola the Magnificent'   },   create: {
> email: 'viola@prisma.io',
> name: 'Viola the Magnificent',
> profileViews: 0,
> role: 'admin'   } }
>
> Unknown arg `email` in where.email for type
> prismaUserWhereUniqueInput. Did you mean `id`? Available args: type
> prismaUserWhereUniqueInput {   id?

My code:
schema.prisma

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model prismaUser {
  id           Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  name         String @db.VarChar(255)
  email        String @db.VarChar(255)
  profileViews Int
  role         String @db.VarChar(255)
}
```

node.js

```
const { PrismaClient } = require("@prisma/client");

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

// A `main` function so that you can use async/await
async function main() {
  await prisma.prismaUser.upsert({
    where: {
      email: "viola@prisma.io",
    },
    update: {
      name: "Viola the Magnificent",
    },
    create: {
      email: "viola@prisma.io",
      name: "Viola the Magnificent",
      profileViews: 0,
      role: "admin",
    },
  });
}

main()
  .catch((e) => {
    throw e;
  })
  .finally(async () => {
    await prisma.$disconnect();
  });
```

Anyone can help me and explain what is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The field in where clause of the `upsert` query should be unique.

In this case, the email field is not unique due to which you are getting this error.

Updating schema file by adding `@unique` attribute to the email field will solve the issue.

```
model prismaUser {
  id           Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  name         String @db.VarChar(255)
  email        String @unique @db.VarChar(255)
  profileViews Int
  role         String @db.VarChar(255)
}
```